# Jplayer not working with some browsers (Probably has something to do with the swf player)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jplayer

I have just set up Jplayer and it is working on chrome, but not on ie or firefox. I set up the demo first and it worked on all three browsers.

I suspect it has something to do with the swf player, but I have no idea what is wrong.

EDIT: Found out what was happening. In the Jplayer js, the swfpath was relative ("js/swfpath"), I changed it to absolute and it worked fine.

The strange thing is that the Net tab in firebug told me that the swf was being correctly downloaded..

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend.  It tells you that "UFO" is not defined on this line:

```
UFO.create(FO, 'slideshow');
```

That means you're not loading ufo.js.

Comment: Why would that have anything to do with jplayer? In fact, I disabled the UFO plugin in case it had anything to do with my problem, but if I load it again, as I did, jplayer still doesnt work...

Comment: That line is where Firefox stops interpreting the JS on your page.  It doesn't matter whether it has something specifically to do with jPlayer or not, that's where execution stops, which stops jPlayer from running, too.  Once you've fixed that error, if the page still doesn't load correctly, enable Firebug and then re-load it again.  You will likely get an error on a different line.